# Using array-like as a type in napoleon without warning

Tags: python, python-sphinx, numpydoc, sphinx-napoleon

I have a project with some functions documented in the napoleon numpy style. In the spirit of numpyness, I have a bunch of function arguments that are of the class `array-like`. Here is an example:

```
def foo(x, y):
    """
    Foo the arguments together to make a bar.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : array-like
        This is an argument.
    y : array-like
        I like it, give me another!

    Returns
    -------
    bar : numpy.ndarray
        Works every time
    """
    pass
```

This works just fine, and the type is included in the output without a link:

[image: generated]

The problem is that I get a warning on every line of every function that has this:

```
/.../my_project/my_module.py:docstring of my_project.my_module.foo:: WARNING: py:class reference target not found: array-like
/.../my_project/my_module.py:docstring of my_project.my_module.foo:: WARNING: py:class reference target not found: array-like
```

I am fairly convinced that there is some solution. It appears that [PR #7690](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/7690) addressed this somehow, but I can't find a meaningful reference "preprocessing" anywhere in the napoleon or broader sphinx documentation.

So how do I get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digging through the PR, I found where to look: the [`napoleon_type_aliases`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html#confval-napoleon_type_aliases) configuration item allows you to set up a mapping for things like `array-like`, `dict-like`, etc. In this particular case, adding the following to `conf.py` did the trick:

```
napoleon_use_param = True
napoleon_type_aliases = {
    'array-like': ':term:`array-like <array_like>`',
    'array_like': ':term:`array_like`',
}
```

[`napoleon_use_param`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html#confval-napoleon_use_param) has to be `True` for this to work. It's documented as defaulting to `True`, but somewhere along the way in my setup, it got unset. It never hurts to be extra safe.

To link to the [`array_like`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/glossary.html#term-array_like) term on the numpy site, the [`intersphinx`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html) extension must be enabled, and [`intersphinx_mapping`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html#confval-intersphinx_mapping) in `conf.py` must link to numpy:

```
intersphinx_mapping = {
    ...
    'numpy': ('https://numpy.org/doc/stable/', None),
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  It's not working for me, however.  I'm still getting a `WARNING: py:class reference target not found: array-like`, but I've included the above material (and added `'sphinx.ext.intersphinx'` to my `extension=`.  Is there anything else I could be missing?  Edit: it does say numpy is being loaded (`loading intersphinx inventory from https://numpy.org/doc/stable/objects.inv...`)